# Get Value of a date from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am working with a travel software and i have to retrieve the rate of a hotel in a particular date.Hotel dates are added between three months(09/01/2015 to 12/31/2015). My database have two columns start date and enddate both are varchar type.The date format is mm/dd/yyyy.I have to retrieve value of single date (11/25/2015). Currently the query i am using is

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_roomtype 
where `room_id`='17' 
  and roomoccupancy='Double' 
  AND startdate<='11/25/2015' 
  and enddate >='11/25/2015'
```

The query is not working perfectly.So anybody can suggest a solution.

Comment: You are not comparing dates, you are comparing *strings*. This will give you different results. This is what happens when you store your dates as strings. Now you need to convert them to dates *first* and then do your comparison.

Comment: _"The query is not working perfectly"_ What... So, is it working or isn't it working? Does it get the dates wrong at some point?

Comment: Since you compare strings you should better change format to `2015/11/25` then `'2015/10/31' < '2015/11/25'` **TRUE** instead of `'31/10/2015' < '25/11/2015'` **FALSE** :-)

Comment: Take a look at [MySQL Date Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html). You can format 25-November-2015 as `20151125`, `2015-11-25`, and a variety of other ways. That makes MySQL treat the value as a date, not a string.

Comment: @EdGibbs Once it's formatted correctly, for this purpose it matters not whether it's treated as a date or a string!

Comment: True @Strawberry. I missed the part about the date field being `varchar`. I'll let this one go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use str_to_date ([str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)).
Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_roomtype 
where `room_id`='17' 
  and roomoccupancy='Double' 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(startdate,'%m/%d/%Y')<=STR_TO_DATE('11/25/2015' ,'%m/%d/%Y')
  and STR_TO_DATE(enddate,'%m/%d/%Y') >=STR_TO_DATE('11/25/2015' ,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse your strings to a valid date. To filter you have to use a string in the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `tbl_roomtype`
WHERE
    `room_id` = '17' 
    AND `roomoccupancy` = 'Double' 
    AND STR_TO_DATE(`startdate`, '%m/%d/%Y') <= '2015-11-25' 
    AND STR_TO_DATE(`enddate`, '%m/%d/%Y') >= '2015-11-25'
```

Or (if you not could fix your filter:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `tbl_roomtype`
WHERE
    `room_id` = '17' 
    AND `roomoccupancy` = 'Double' 
    AND STR_TO_DATE(`startdate`, '%m/%d/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('11/25/2015', '%m/%d/%Y') 
    AND STR_TO_DATE(`enddate`, '%m/%d/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('11/25/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
```